# PYTHON Format percentage as numeric

Tags: python

I have a question about converting a string output to a numeric output

For example:

```
a = "{0:.2f}%".format(float(0.21*100))

a = '21.00%'

type(a)

str
```

I want the output in excel to show 21.00%  in the cell which format is a numeric value no a string.

Thank you~

Comment: You mean like `a = 0.21*100`?

Comment: A numeric value can't have `%` in it. That requires string formatting.

Comment: "I want the output at excel"???

Comment: If you want a numeric value stored in a cell in Excel but you want it to be displayed as a percentage with decimals then you store it as `0.21` in Excel but use Excel's formatting to display it as `21.00%`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the percent, or you can't change it to a numeric.

```
float(a.replace("%", ""))
```

The better option is to just leave it at `a = (0.21*100)`